# Other websites redirecting through mine

Tags: c#, redirect, url-parameters

We have a homebrewed advertising system on our website. Part of this includes code that when an ad is clicked, we first go to a intermediary page that records the click data, which then redirects them along to the desired advertiser's website.

Unfortunately, our current solution requires that a URL parameter be passed to the intermediary page that is the destination URL. Some savvy advertisers have discovered that they can use this for their own nefarious purposes and "launder" their traffic through our site. In other words, on their site, they have a link along the lines of www.oursite.com/redirect?URL=www.theirtargetsite.com, making it seem like that traffic is coming from our site.

I'm working on a solution that will only redirect to a whitelist of URLs, but my first problem is more just knowing what this is called. Finding alternative and probably better solutions is difficult when I don't even know what to call it. With so much spoofing, laundering, and hijacking going on, it's hard to find help for the right topic.

What is it called when website A redirects to website C through website B without the permission of B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word you're looking for is *open redirect*. [The MITRE article on this class of vulnerability](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/601.html) has some examples of ways that this can be mitigated, e.g:

- Whitelist the URLs that you will redirect to
- Displaying a warning page before redirecting (probably not viable in your situation)
- Use numbers to identify the URLs to redirect to (i.e, look them up in a table) instead of putting the target in a query parameter
- Use a HMAC construction to "sign" URLs to redirect to, and reject redirects that don't have a valid signature

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the vocab lesson as well as the suggestions.